# How do I close all connections to my server?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a sever that Accepts/Revives and sends to Client Connections Asynchronously.
I am using Tcp.

All Connections are saved to the list when accepted:

```
    List<Socket> clientConnections = new List<Socket>();
```

How can I disconnect all clients gracefully?
***Please note I am not trying to detect client disconnects. Rather I want to force clients to disconnect.***

My code structure:

```
class ServerListener
{
    List<Socket> clientConnections = new List<Socket>();
    Socket ServerSocket;

    public ServerListener(IPAddress IP, int Port)
    {
        ServerSocket = new Socket(IP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        ServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IP, Port));

        ServerSocket.Listen(10);
        Program.mainForm.changeStatus(frmServer.status.online);
        Program.mainForm.displayIP(((IPEndPoint)ServerSocket.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString());
        try
        {
            ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = ServerSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            clientConnections.Add(client);
            client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), client);
            ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    void RecieveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int len = client.EndReceive(AR);
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[len];

        Array.Copy(buffer, tempBuffer, len);
        string request = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tempBuffer);

        try
        {
            byte[] sendBuffer = HandleRequest(request);
            client.BeginSend(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client); // send data
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            client.Close();
            clientConnections.Remove(client);
            DisplayClientRequestInfo("User Disconnected.");
        }
    }

    void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        client.EndSend(AR);

        client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), client);
    }

    // listening for changes
    public delegate void textRecievedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string message);
    public event textRecievedEventHandler messageChanged;

    protected virtual void DisplayClientRequestInfo(string message)
    {
        if (messageChanged != null)
        {
            messageChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty, message);
        }
    }

    // handling requests

    byte[] HandleRequest(string request)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        // Create the response...

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
             // disconnect Here

            ServerSocket.Dispose();

            foreach (Socket s in clientConnections)
            {
                KickUser(s);
            }   
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DisplayClientRequestInfo(e.Message);
        }
    }

    void KickUser(Socket socket)
    {
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();
    }
}
```

So when the user clicks the "Stop Server" Button it will run:

```
sl.Stop();
```

Where sl is an instance of ServerListener.

When a client is connected and I stop the server, I get the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.

I think this is because the connections Asynchronous. Also on the client side the `socket.Connected` is `true`. meaning it still thinks its connected to the server.

So Whats the correct way to safely kick users from the server?

Comment: Hmm similar question to mine yes, but the answer really isn't helpful. It explains why it behaves the way it does. But not how to fix it.

Comment: See #3 in the answer there, you should probably loop through all of your `Socket` instances and call `Shutdown` on each of them before you `Close`/`Dispose` anything, but it's been a while since I did any sockets programming myself.

Comment: Taking a closer look the question did help me understand a bit more, Thanks. According to some of the research I did the `Dispose` method was the same as `Shutdown` it just 'eats the errors'

Comment: In my code I am looping though and shutting down before closing. refer to the `KickUser` method

Comment: Oh wait I get it, I'm supposed to call `socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);`. and then do the loop for zero bytes. Thanks a lot @gmiley

Comment: Right, it appears as though you were mostly doing everything correctly, it was just slightly out of order. Unfortunately, that is enough to bork the entire process. =)